# Delete all values within a registry key using C#

Tags: c#, outlook, add-in

I'm having trouble finding a method to delete all values within a registry key without actually deleting the key itself. I would rather not have to delete the key because I'd rather not deal with re-adding the appropriate permissions back to the key.

I'm trying to have a small method run to simply clear out the values from:

**HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Resiliency\DisabledItems**

We have an add-in that Outlook periodically sticks in here, and our techs have to dig into this key and remove the values, restart Outlook and all is well.

I guess we could just identify the exact name of the value, but that wouldn't be very fun :) and because the way that the values are named in this key, it is not apparent which one points to the correct add-in.

Comment: Why not just delete the entire key, then add it back in again as an empty one?

Comment: please re-read part of my question: **I would rather not have to delete the key because I'd rather not deal with re-adding the appropriate permissions back to the key.** Obviously if this is the only option then so be it.

Comment: Can you show what you've tried? Seems like using `RegistryKey.GetValueNames()` and `RegistryKey.DeleteValue` should do the job of enumerating the values and then deleting them.

Comment: There is a search function in the upper right hand corner.  Type in C# Registry Loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with Ron Beyer. I think this might be what you are looking for? Edit the registry paths and HKLM/HKCU as needed.

```
        string keyPath64Bit = "SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Krondorian";
        RegistryKey localMachine = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64);
        RegistryKey key64Bit = localMachine.OpenSubKey(keyPath64Bit, true);

        if (key64Bit != null)
        {
            var namesArray = key64Bit.GetValueNames();
            foreach (string valueName in namesArray)
            {
                key64Bit.DeleteValue(valueName);
            }
        }
```